# Каков статус выражения "за нами за всеми"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексика

Обычное сочетание выглядит так: ***за всеми нами.***

Но "за нами за всеми" тоже иногда встречается, например: *Однажды **за нами за всеми** придут. Но кто это будет – зависит только от нас.*

Есть ли у этого сочетания дополнительный смысл и можно ли его считать нормативным?

Comment: Могу сказать, что такое встречается в народной речи — фразы такого типа: *на горе на высокой*.

Comment: Ещё могу сказать, что повторение предлога здесь усиливает тревогу.

Comment: Прикольный вопрос, поставлю лайк, буду первым.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нормативным явно считать нельзя. С этим трудно поспорить. Но разговорным — вполне.

Повторение предлога здесь усиливает смысл.

Не раз сталкивался с подобными фразами. В основном такое встречал в народных песнях.

Здесь "за всеми нами" почему-то не сильно подходит. Лучше — "за нами всеми". Наверно, "всеми" надо подчеркнуть за счёт такой позиции.

Comment: В общем похоже на правду, повтор всегда выглядит как усиление и подчеркивание. Но я думала, что это устойчивое выражение (библейское, может быть) или из фразеологического словаря. А то вот напишите так, а вас поправят. Хотелось бы в ответ ссылку какую предъявить.

Comment: Со ссылкой глухо.

Comment: Нашёл такой пример: https://znanija.com/task/13160641

Comment: Не открывается ссылка

Comment: Вот Google-копия: https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:U2KKtC_IO64J:https://znanija.com/task/13160641&cd=1&hl=ru&ct=clnk&gl=ua

Comment: Так это песня. Понятное дело, что такие повторы встречаются. Мне хотелось что-нибудь для этого конкретного сочетания.

Comment: Фразеологического значения (переносного смысла) здесь точно нет. Особой устойчивости (когда фраза известна, на слуху) тоже.